# Mostrar entradas con parametros por GET y custom fields

Tags: wordpress

Estoy haciendo un loop en Wordpress para que busque aquellos posts que cuyo valor del custom field 'pais' sea igual al $_GET['s']

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'post', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'=> 's',
            'metavalue'   => 'pais',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);  

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

            ?><h2><?php the_title();?></h2><?php                                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de `$_GET['s']`, te recomiendo utilizar la siguiente función, que *sanitiza* los datos introducidos por el usuario en el campo de búsqueda: [`get_search_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_search_query)

El operador de comparación por defecto es `'meta_compare' => '='`, así que no es necesario ponerlo.

Sería algo así:

```
$keyword = get_search_query();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'pais',
    'meta_value' => $keyword
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar entradas que coincida un custom field con un $_GET (o con una variable en general), hay que usar como comparacion `==` `!=` `>=` `<=`, como si se tratara de una condicional en PHP.

La `key` es el nombre del custom field, mientras que el `value`, es la variable que almacena, en este caso, el dato obtenido por `GET`.

```
$pais = $_GET['pais'];

if( isset($_GET['pais']) ){

$args= array(
    'post_type'=>'post', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'pais',
            'value' => $pais,
            'compare' => '==',
        )            
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post(); 

        // The Loop

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @MarisabelGC si esta es la respuesta correcta no olvides marcarla como tal, saludos.